# firebaseのauthenticationについて困っています

Tags: firebase

初めての投稿で至らぬ点もございますがご了承いただけたら幸いです。
GoogleのFirebaseを使ってログイン機能を実装しており、現在ログインしているユーザーがいる場合の処理（`Auth.auth().currentuser != nil {}`）といったものを書いていたところ、まったくcurrentuserがnilになりません。もしかしたらほんとにおバカさんな発言なのかもしれませんが、恥ずかしながら初心者で大真面目です。

グーグルサインインのボタンを押したらサインインしながら画面遷移して、
それ以外のボタンを押したらサインインをしない状態のまま画面遷移という実装をしたいです。

どなたかご教授お願いいたします。

以下コードです。

AppDelegate.swift

```swift
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,GIDSignInDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FirebaseApp.configure()
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()!.options.clientID
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
        if user != nil {
            user?.delete(completion: nil)
        }

//      初回起動のUserDefault群
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let HomeDic = ["HomeFirstPop": true]
        defaults.register(defaults: HomeDic)
        let MapDic = ["MapFirstPop": true]
        defaults.register(defaults: MapDic)
        let SearchDic = ["SearchFirstPop": true]
        defaults.register(defaults: SearchDic)
        let RankDic = ["RankFirstPop": true]
        defaults.register(defaults: RankDic)
        let MypageDic = ["MypageDic": true]
        defaults.register(defaults: MypageDic)
        return true

    }

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        if let error = error {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        let authentication = user.authentication
        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: (authentication?.idToken)!, accessToken: (authentication?.accessToken)!)
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential, completion: { (user, error) in
            print("You could signin with google")
        })
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        print("Sign off successfully")
    }

}
```

SigninViewController

```swift
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import GoogleSignIn

class SignInViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

    var userRef: DatabaseReference!
    let thisUser = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self

        userRef = Database.database().reference().child("users")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


//  サインインのときに呼び出されるメソッド。必須メソッド
    @IBAction func signinWithGoogle(_ sender: GIDSignInButton) {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let nextView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nextView") as! UITabBarController
        nextView.selectedIndex = 2
        self.present(nextView, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }



// ログアウトボタンからログイン画面に戻ってくるためのメソッド
    @IBAction func backToTop(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()

    }

    @IBAction func NoSignInButton(_ sender: Any) {

        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            print("サインインしてるよ")
            print(Auth.auth().currentUser as Any)
        } else {
            let NextTabbarController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nextView") as! UITabBarController

            NextTabbarController.selectedIndex = 2
            self.present(NextTabbarController, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

初期化したすぐの状態ではcurrentUserはnilなので準備ができたかを確認するには
認証状態をlistenする必要があります。
次のドキュメントを参照してください。

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start#listen_for_authentication_state

addStateDidChangeListenerはログインされていなければcallback引数のuserがnilで呼び出され、ログインしていればオブジェクトが入っています。

addStateDidChangeListenerのcallbackが呼び出されるまではローディング画面を表示しておくなどするとよいでしょう。

Comment: コメントは避けてくださいと書かれていましたが言わせてください！！本当にありがとうございます！！！！！！助かりました！！つまり、これからログインしているのかを確認する場合にはaddStateDidChangeListenerを使用していけば良いということでよろしいんですよね？

Comment: あともうなんかありがたすぎていろいろ出来る限りのことしたいです！バッチ？？みたいなの送ることできますか？